# Reading dictionary structure from text file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

I have file where I have defined python dictionary:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First', 'Friends': {'Emil':1, 'Frank':0} };
```

I want to read this dictionary and use it's element in python code. I've end up with following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import ast
import re
from pprint import pprint as pp

def readObjFromFile(file):
  with open (file, "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
  data = re.sub("^#.*", "", data)
  data = data.replace('\n', '')
  data = data.split("=", 1)[1].split(";", 1)[0].lstrip()
  data = ast.literal_eval(data)
  return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 1:
    dict = readObjFromFile(sys.argv[1])
    print type(dict)
    pp(dict)
  else:
    print "Pass file from which object will be read"
    exit
```

This works also for [this](http://termbin.com/s4sq) larger dictionary. I want to ask if there is better way to do it? I am aware of `pickle` module but this is not what I want because it stores data in it's own format. I was considering modules which are used for parsing json due to similarity with python dicts, but I do not know if this approach is safe.

Comment: Why don't you just pickle?

Comment: This is so close to JSON, there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: The one thing you definitely _don't_ want to do is try to store things as Python source code and then read them back by trying to parse it with regex…

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean by "safe"? JSON and `literal_eval` are both very limited formats and therefore _generally_ safe for _most_ things, but without knowing what kind of attack you're worried about, it's hard to say anything in more detail than that

Comment: Or, if you meant "safe" in the sense of "robust" rather than "secure", that's also hard to say. The `json` module will give you clear, easy-to-handle exceptions if you try to store something that isn't JSON-able (basically, dict/list/int/float/str/bool/NoneType), and decent debugging information if you try to load something that isn't valid output. Is that what you want?

Comment: Just use the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: @Zizouz212 because when you look at pickle format http://spootnik.org/entries/2014/04/05_diving-into-the-python-pickle-format.html or http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/11/22/python-101-an-intro-to-object-serialization-with-pickle/ you will see that it somehow "converts" python object and then store them. So the result is not "plain text" as my example.

Comment: @abarnert by safe I mean if both json and python dicts are equivalent. For example if python dict contains something that cannot be properly written in json then json parser will not recognize this?

Comment: @WakanTanka: If a Python dict contains something that cannot be properly written in JSON, then you'll get an error at _save_ time (`json.dump` or `json.dumps`)—which is a lot better than saving it with `repr` (which will always succeed) and then not getting an error until load time (`literal_eval`) when your original data may no longer exist. (And to a reasomably close approximation, the things that will fail in JSON `dumps`/`loads` are the same things that will fail in `repr`/`literal_eval`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't have control over the file format and are being handed it from somewhere. It's close enough to json that I'd aim to make it json. I'd do something like the following:

```
lines = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == "#":
            continue
        l = line.strip().split("=")[-1].strip(";")
        lines.append(re.sub("'", "\"", l)
return json.loads("".join(lines))
```

Comment: Are both json and python dicts equivalent (in syntactic way). For example if python dict contains something that cannot be properly written in json (is this possible?) then json parser will not recognize this?

Answer (score 2):

The file you have really represents a human interpreted version of the dictionary.  We can read it and see how there is a variable that we want to assign to a dictionary.  What you really want to do is store the dict in a programatic friendly format.  And JSON is a perfect use of this format.  Other formats include XML and YAML, but Python natively and easily will read JSON input.

If you look closely at your example, you see that the sample data set has a dictionary with a nested dictionary.  JSON is built for these kinds of use cases.  So a JSON file with your data above would look like:

```
{
    "Name": "Zara", 
    "Age": 7, 
    "Class": "First", 
    "Friends": {
        "Emil":1, 
        "Frank":0
    } 
}
```

Note the sub-dictionary is part of the structure of the JSON file.  Also note that double quotes are used.

Now you can easily have python do your work for you:

```
import json
from os import open
from pprint import pprint

data = open(filename).read()
d = json.loads(data)
pprint(d)
```

And you can access the submodules by using:

```
d['Friends]
```

Comment: Are both json and python dicts equivalent (in syntactic way). For example if python dict contains something that cannot be properly written in json (is this possible?) then json parser will not recognize this?

Comment: JSON has its own specification and the Python JSON parsing module has a number of limitations (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#standard-compliance-and-interoperability).  However, it covers many, many common use cases.